# Convert decimal string representation of an int to "bytes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I need to convert an int, such as `123456`, to bytes in the format `b'123456'`. I'm not doing an actual conversion to bytes however, I'm just changing the format to look like a byte and be interpreted as one. So I literally need to do the following:

```
10 = b'10'
20 = b'20'
30 = b'30'
```

and so. I can't convert to a string because I need the results to be in bytes, and I can't do an actual byte conversion because `bytes([10]) == b'\n'` (and not `b'10'`).

Comment: `str(10).encode()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the `int` to a `str` then `.encode` into `bytes`:

```
>>> x = 123456
>>> bs = str(x).encode('ascii')
>>> bs
b'123456'
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about what `10`, `20` and `30` actually are. Sure, they are numbers, but exactly that `10` is just a [decimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation) of the actual number. Usually, there are many different representation of a single number. For example `0xA`, `0o12` and `0b1010` are different representations of the same number that is written as `10` in its decimal representation.

So first, you should think about how to get that decimal representation of a number. Luckily, that’s very easy since the decimal representation is the general default for numbers. So you just have to convert your number into a string by calling the [`str()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str):

```
>>> str(10)
'10'
>>> str(20)
'20'
```

Once you do that, you have a string with the correct representation of your number. So all that’s left is asking how to convert that *string* into a `bytes` object. In Python 3, a `bytes` object is just a sequence of bytes. So in order to convert a string into a byte sequence, you have to decide how to represent each character in your string. This process is called encoding, and is done using [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode). For characters from the ASCII range, the actual encoding does not really matter as it is the same in all common encodings, so you can just stick with the default UTF-8:

```
>>> '10'.encode()
b'10'
>>> '20'.encode()
b'20'
```

So now you have everything you need. Just combine these two things, and you can convert your numbers into a `bytes` object of its decimal representation:

```
>>> str(10).encode()
b'10'
>>> str(20).encode()
b'20'
```