# Incorrect use of byte strings in Python CRC16 implementation?

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement my own [cyclic redundancy check (CRC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) in Python. The layout of my program is as follows:

1. random_message(n) generates a random byte message of length n.
2. Generate the checksum value using the CRC code `crc16`.
3. Run the corruption code `corrupt_data` on the generated message.
4. Check whether the checksum is different or not (I did this using `==`).
5. Repeat steps 1 to 4 many times to see how often an error (i.e., the corruption) goes unnoticed.

I am confident that the methods `crc16` and `corrupt_data` are correct, so I don't think there's much reason to analyse them too closely. I think the problems start with my use of byte strings in the second half of my program, after those two methods.

My code is as follows:

```
from random import random
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

CORRUPTION_RATE = 0.25

def crc16(data: bytes):
    xor_in = 0x0000  # initial value
    xor_out = 0x0000  # final XOR value
    poly = 0x8005  # generator polinom (normal form)

    reg = xor_in
    for octet in data:
        # reflect in
        for i in range(8):
            topbit = reg & 0x8000
            if octet & (0x80 >> i):
                topbit ^= 0x8000
            reg <<= 1
            if topbit:
                reg ^= poly
        reg &= 0xFFFF
        # reflect out
    return reg ^ xor_out

from random import randbytes


def corrupt_data(data : bytes):
    '''
    some random corruption of byte data
    can be modified as needed using the CORRUPTION_RATE global constant
    ''' 
    temp = data[:]
    while True:
        location = int(len(temp) * random())
        data_list = list(temp)
        if random() < 0.5:
            data_list[location] = (data_list[location] + 1) % 256
        else: 
            data_list[location] = (data_list[location] - 1) % 256
        temp = bytes(data_list)
        if random() < CORRUPTION_RATE and temp != data:
            break
    return temp

# Generate random byte message of length n
def random_message(n):
    
    randomBytes = ''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(n)).encode()
    print("randomBytes is " + str(randomBytes))
    print("The class type of randomBytes is " + str(type(randomBytes)))
    return randomBytes

    
    
numberOfErrors = 0;

for i in range(10000):

    # generating random byte message of length n
    randomMessage = random_message(5)

    # generating the checksum value using the CRC code
    checksumValue = crc16(randomMessage)
    #print("checksumValue is " + str(checksumValue))
    #print("The class type of checksumValue is " + str(type(checksumValue)))

    # running the corruption on the generated message
    #print("The class type of bchecksumValue is " + str(type(b"checksumValue")))
    corrupt = corrupt_data(b"checksumValue")
    #print("The class type of corrupt_data(bchecksumValue) is " + str(type(corrupt)))

    #print("Checking whether the checksum is different ... ")
    different = (b"checksumValue" == corrupt)
    #print("bchecksumValue == corrupt is " + str(different))
    #print("bchecksumValue was " + str(b"checksumValue") + ", and corrupt was " + str(corrupt))
    
    if(different == False):
        numberOfErrors += 1
        
print("numberOfErrors is " + str(numberOfErrors))
```

As you can see, I've inserted various (now commented out) print statements to help me with debugging.

The problem is that, when I run the above code, I get that `numberOfErrors is 10000`. Obviously, this can't be correct, since we expect some of them to be correct, and so we expect `numberOfErrors` to be somewhat less than 10000.

As I said, I am confident that the `crc16` and `corrupt_data` functions are correct, and I suspect that the problem is arising somewhere in my use of the byte strings inside the for loop:

```
numberOfErrors = 0;

for i in range(10000):

    # generating random byte message of length n
    randomMessage = random_message(5)

    # generating the checksum value using the CRC code
    checksumValue = crc16(randomMessage)
    #print("checksumValue is " + str(checksumValue))
    #print("The class type of checksumValue is " + str(type(checksumValue)))

    # running the corruption on the generated message
    #print("The class type of bchecksumValue is " + str(type(b"checksumValue")))
    corrupt = corrupt_data(b"checksumValue")
    #print("The class type of corrupt_data(bchecksumValue) is " + str(type(corrupt)))

    #print("Checking whether the checksum is different ... ")
    different = (b"checksumValue" == corrupt)
    #print("bchecksumValue == corrupt is " + str(different))
    #print("bchecksumValue was " + str(b"checksumValue") + ", and corrupt was " + str(corrupt))
    
    if(different == False):
        numberOfErrors += 1
        
print("numberOfErrors is " + str(numberOfErrors))
```

I've never really programmed with bytes / byte strings, and I've also only just recently started learning Python, so I don't understand what I'm doing incorrectly. Where's my error, and how do I fix it?

---

### EDIT

As mentioned by *user2357112 supports Monica* in the comments, the problem might be `b"checksumValue"` in `corrupt = corrupt_data(b"checksumValue")`. The problem I had was that the function `crc16` returns an int, so, in order to convert it back into bytes for passing into the function `corrupt_data(data : bytes)`, I tried using the `b` prefix. I guess this is my Python inexperience showing.

---

### EDIT2

Ok, so I'm trying the solution offered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533979/6828329) answer. The modified code is as follows:

```
# running the corruption on the generated message
bs = str(checksumValue).encode('ascii')
print("str(checksumValue).encode('ascii') is " + str(bs))
#print("The class type of bchecksumValue is " + str(type(b"checksumValue")))
print("The class type of str(checksumValue).encode('ascii') is " + str(type(bs)))
#corrupt = corrupt_data(b"checksumValue")
corrupt = corrupt_data(bs)
#print("The class type of corrupt_data(bchecksumValue) is " + str(type(corrupt)))
print("The class type of corrupt_data(bs) is " + str(type(corrupt)))
```

The output is

```
randomBytes is b'BBVFC'
The class type of randomBytes is <class 'bytes'>
checksumValue is 10073
The class type of checksumValue is <class 'int'>
str(checksumValue).encode('ascii') is b'10073'
The class type of str(checksumValue).encode('ascii') is <class 'bytes'>
The class type of corrupt_data(bs) is <class 'bytes'>
```

So the classes seem to match with what we'd expect.

---

### EDIT3

Implementing the changes in EDIT2 in the for loop, I still get `numberOfErrors is 10000` as my output. The code is as follows:

```
numberOfErrors = 0;

for i in range(10000):

    # generating random byte message of length n
    randomMessage = random_message(5)

    # generating the checksum value using the CRC code
    checksumValue = crc16(randomMessage)
    #print("checksumValue is " + str(checksumValue))
    #print("The class type of checksumValue is " + str(type(checksumValue)))

    # running the corruption on the generated message
    bs = str(checksumValue).encode('ascii')
    #print("str(checksumValue).encode('ascii') is " + str(bs))
    #print("The class type of str(checksumValue).encode('ascii') is " + str(type(bs)))
    corrupt = corrupt_data(bs)
    #print("The class type of corrupt_data(bs) is " + str(type(corrupt)))
    
    #print("Checking whether the checksum is different ... ")
    different = (bs == corrupt)
    #print("bs == corrupt is " + str(different))
    #print("bs was " + str(bs) + ", and corrupt was " + str(corrupt))
    
    if(different == False):
        numberOfErrors += 1
        
print("numberOfErrors is " + str(numberOfErrors))
```

Comment: Suggestion: can you trim done your question at all? Is there anything in there that's not fundamental to the question being asked? Doing so may help you (or someone else) figure out the problem more quickly.

Comment: @mackorone Hmm, are you referring to the numbering 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.? Those aren't questions, they're just giving a quick overview of the layout of the program. Or are you referring to something else? As I mention in the second part of my post, the `crc16` and `corrupt_data` functions are not the problem, so those can be taken as correct; the problem is likely in the second half of my code, which I repasted.

Comment: I just mean: that's a lot of code, and is probably not all necessary to reproduce your error. Pruning away the stuff that's working will help you (and others) focus in on the problematic parts. Often, the exercise of narrowing down what part is broken can even lead you to a solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `b"checksumValue"` is not the checksum value.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ahh, I knew it would be something like that. I tried to use `b"checksumValue"` to convert it from an int back to bytes, because `crc16` actually returns an int.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Do you think `int.to_bytes()` would work instead? The arguments to this are quite confusing, so I'm not sure exactly how to implement it correctly https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-an-int-to-bytes-in-python

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari When I enable the print statement, it says `The class type of corrupt_data(bchecksumValue) is <class 'bytes'>`, so it seems correct. The problem is that this could be originating from, as *user2357112 supports Monica* said, `corrupt = corrupt_data(b"checksumValue")` directly before it, since the `b"checksumValue"` looks like it might be incorrect.

Comment: To make it easier for readers, I will go back through my post and try to further emphasise the relevant parts that most likely require attention.

Comment: Does that help at all?

Comment: Please stop making this even longer! It’s very difficult to figure out what you are asking about what block of code, least of all where to even begin troubleshooting. Please review the [mcve] and [ask] help pages and try to remove as much nonessential content as possible.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Oh, sorry. I will go through it and start cutting things out.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Shall I also remove comments, even though they're used for debugging?

Comment: "Obviously, this can't be correct, since we expect some of them to be correct" Talk me through why you think this is true. In particular, it seems as though you expect that `corrupt_data` will return the unmodified input at least some of the time. Try to explain what has to happen in order to get that result.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, according to *Blckknght*'s answer, it seems that I confused myself.

Comment: There are many conceptually wrong things here, but the underlying idea is to *think more clearly*. Think about what value you want to pass to your functions - should it be a variable or a literal? Write out the steps logically in plain English words first: corrupt the plaintext, compute the checksum of the original, compute the checksum of the corrupted version, see if the checksums are equal. Then step through the code you are writing and make sure that it actually corresponds to those steps.

Comment: Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Will do. Thanks, Karl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with the byte strings really, it's a logical error. You're trying to corrupt the wrong thing. You don't want to corrupt the checksum, you want to corrupt the original message and then take a checksum of the corrupted version. Then you can compare if the two checksums match or not.

Try:

```
undetected_errors = 0

for i in range(10000):
    good_message = random_message(5)
    good_checksum = crc16(good_message)

    corrupted_message = corrupt_data(good_message)
    corrupted_checksum = crc16(corrupted_message)

    if good_checksum == corrupted_checksum:
        undetected_errors += 1
```